# Show that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are pairwise independent but not independent.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X_1,X_2$ be iid RVs with common PMF:
$$P(X = \pm1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

We define $X_3 = X_1X_2$. Show that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are pairwise independent but not independent.

I have shown that these RV's are pairwise independent. How can I prove that these are not independent?

Comment: Is $P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3) = P(X_1=x_1)P(X_2=x_2)P(X_3=x_3)$ ?

Comment: Take $x_1=x_2=x_3=1$ in above comment and compute the probabilities.

Comment: I have written the sample space and I've got my answers.

Comment: @AxyuS Feel free to write your own answer and accept it then.